# tinymce and sonata admin, how to add tables option

Tags: symfony, tinymce, sonata-admin

I can't find any information on how to enable specific plugins via sonata.

Here's what I have which works great, but it's the "basic" tinymce.

```
 ->add('text', 'textarea', array('attr' => array('class' => 'tinymce', 'tinymce'=>'{"theme":"simple"}')))
```

I've tried

```
 ->add('text', 'textarea', array('attr' => array('class' => 'tinymce', 'tinymce'=>'{"theme":"advanced"}')))
```

but that doesn't do anything.

Does anyone have a clue ?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, use data-theme:

```
->add('text', 'textarea', array('attr' => array('class' => 'tinymce', 'data-theme' => 'advanced')))
```